# Understanding Python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python & understanding the coding. I tried two sets of code, but for the below second line, I couldn't execute. can you plz explain why?

```
distance = np.array([0.723,1.0,1.524,5.203])
distance = [0.723,1.0,1.524,5.203]

flux = 1370 / (distance**2)
```

When I execute the second part (Line2) instead of first-line I get an error, Plz help me to understand:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: the distance datatype is `list`

Comment: What is your expected result? Also, you defining distance twice, effectively overwriting the first array.

Comment: `np.array`s are different from "normal" `list`s in python, they don't support vectorized computations, you have to iterate through them of use `map` and pass a function to do what you want

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because the second instantiated variable distance
`distance = [0.723,1.0,1.524,5.203]` is a python list which doesn't support the power operator `**`.

So, you should just stick to numpy array.

```
distance = np.array([0.723,1.0,1.524,5.203])
flux = 1370 / (distance**2)
```

Which gives result `array([2620.86090498, 1370.,  589.86229084,   50.60727062])`

You can get python list result if you want with:

```
>>> flux.tolist()
[2620.8609049813576, 1370.0, 589.8622908356928, 50.607270624669916]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work in form of `list` you have to iterate via `for` or `while` loop

**One way is:-**

```
distance = [0.723,1.0,1.524,5.203]
for i in distance:
    flux = 1370 / (i**2)
    print(flux)
```

**Output:-**

```
2620.8609049813576
1370.0
589.8622908356928
50.607270624669916
```